# How to get name to an input by checking radio button in react?

Tags: reactjs

I have got series of data that contains some objects in one array(json file) and it will be shown by react .

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: [],
            .
            .
        }
    } 
}
```

I have got multiple items :

```
render() {

    const { data, currentPage, itemsPerPage } = this.state;
    const indexOfLastItem = currentPage * itemsPerPage;
    const indexOfFirstItem = indexOfLastItem - itemsPerPage;
    const currentItems = data.slice(indexOfFirstItem, indexOfLastItem);
    const renderTour = currentItems.map((item, i) => {
        return <div class="item">{this.renderInfo(item)}</div>
            .......
    </form>
    }) 
}
```

In each item there are some divs by `className="boxInput"` and in each boxInput div there is an input by `type="radio"` and an input by `type="hidden"`.

```
renderInfo(element,i,idx,idj){
    if (i==1) {
        return (
            <div class="boxInput">
                <input type="hidden" name={`_root.rooms__${idx}.roomids__${idj}.roomid`} value={element.info.roomid} />///////input1////////
                <input type="radio"  onClick={((e) => this.handleCheck(e, element,i,idx,idj))}  name={`InputRadio${idj}`} />///////radio1////////
            </div>
        )
    } else {
        return (
            <div class="boxInput">
                <input type="hidden" name="" value={element.info.roomid} />///////input2////////
                <input type="radio"   onClick={((e) => this.handleCheck(e, element,i,idx,idj))} name={`InputRadio${idj}`}  />///////radio2////////
           </div>
        )
    }
}
```

As you can see in the first boxInput div the `input="hidden"` has got the name and `input="radio"` is checked.
I want when radio2 is checked input2 gets name

```
name={`_root.rooms__${idx}.roomids__${idj}.roomid`}
```

and the attribute name of input1 will be empty(`name=""`).
How can I do it?